# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL 405 error

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, methods, get

I did a small form and corresponding servlet as below. Getting error.

**HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
type Status report
message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.43**

Dont understand why. As per my understanding when we do not give any method attribute in a form by default it takes GET. Accordingly I override the doGet method and removed any super calls. But still it fails. Whereas when I explicitly set the attribute method="POST" it is working. But I dont want to put the method POST. I want to view the default GET behavior. What is wrong in my code.

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World Java EE</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
        alert('Submit button clicked');
        document.getElementById("demoForm").submit();   
    }
</script>

<body>
    <h1>Hello JSP and Servlet!</h1>
    <form id="demoForm" action="helloServlet">
        Enter your name: 
        <input type="text" name="yourName" size="20">
        <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> -->
        <button id="submitProject" style="font-size: 93%;" onClick='submitForm()'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet Class

```
package net.codejava.javaee;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/helloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
    }
    
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String yourName = request.getParameter("yourName");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h1>Hello " + yourName + "</h1>");
        writer.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        String yourName = req.getParameter("yourName");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h1>Hello " + yourName + "</h1>");
        writer.close();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Double check that the class file has been compiled from the current version of the code (e.g. file timestamps).

Comment: Did that... That worked... But another problem I am facing. I did the method GET and POST and accordingly I am getting the output. Thats fine. But in case when I did it POST when I change the URL in browser manually to GET type the form still gets submitted. Is there any way to prevent it. Means I want when I will put method POST it will do POST only. User cannot chane the query string manually and submit the form.

Comment: If you write a URL in your browser's address field, you will perform a GET request.